# Rearanging bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in Bootstap-

```css
.message-preview {
  background-color: green;
  height:100px;
}
.inbox-preview {
  background-color: blue;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class = "container">
     <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-4">
       <div class='inbox-preview'>
        
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-8">
       <div class='message-preview'>
        
       </div>
      </div>
    
     </div>
    </div>
```

In a big screen, this is what it looks like- 
[image]

In a smaller screen, say between `xs` and `md` widths, I want it to look like this - 
[image]

Since I technically want a rearranging of the columns, I don't know how to do this. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **column reordering** classes (push and pull) to do this. [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

**Working Example:**

```css
.message-preview {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
.inbox-preview {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4">
      <div class='message-preview'>
        message-preview
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8">
      <div class='inbox-preview'>
        inbox-preview
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @vanburen, this works perfectly! :D